# Material UI tab selected has different color than the rest of tabs

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

New to Material UI so hopefully this question makes sense. I am using Material UI Tabs and have been able to customize the css as per need. see below:

[image: Tab]

I have an issue where the selected tab and the other tabs have different opacity(?) even though they are the same color. Cannot find any material UI documentation online to make them uniform, I tried several things [TabIndicatorProps] or even adding below to the Tabs class

```
"&.Mui-selected": {
      color: "1D4659",
      opacity: "70%"
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I can change either the selected tab or the Other tabs. I just want to make sure they are uniform.

Comment: Have you tried "opacity: 0.7"?

Comment: You could also have a css specificity hierarchy issue where the id is applying styling, which would overrule any css applied to a class.

Comment: I did. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `MuiTab-root` instead of `Mui-selected`.

1- declare your custom style

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customTabs: {
    "& .MuiTab-root": {
      color: "#1D4659",
      opacity: "70%"
    }
  }
});
```

2- use your custom style in `<Tabs>`

```
     const classes = useStyles();

     <Tabs
        classes={{ root: classes.customTabs }}
        ...
      >
       <Tab ... />
       <Tab ... />
       <Tab ... />
       <Tab ... />
       <Tab ... />
    </Tabs>
```

here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-framework-xo1cp?file=/src/App.js